# iTerm2 - hide split pane title bars?

Tags: macos, look-and-feel, iterm

After recent update of iTerm2 the split panes look different:

[image: how it looks now]

This is how it looked before (some random image found on the Internet):

[image: how it looked before]

Is there a way to get the original look back or do I have to get used to it?

Edit: just to avoid confusion, what I'm concerned about are the "header" lines, the "(x) Default" thing. I'd like to have just a line there.

Edit 2: it's in [this changelog](http://groups.google.com/group/iterm2-discuss/browse_thread/thread/8b7af79c410b4993):

```
- Add title bars to split panes that show the title. You can drag 
panes by their titles, and there is a menu and a close button in it as 
well.
```

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Turn off prefs->appearance->show per-pane title bars with split panes.

[image]